# Gcloud, Relase external IP

Tags: google-compute-engine

So I'm currently really new to google cloud platform and I have an issue to be solved.
I've already created a compute engine in gcloud. When it was created, it automatically assigned an external IP. I'd prefer the instances to not have any external IP.
I saw that you could put [--no-address](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) argument when creating the instances so it wouldn't be assigned an external IP, but how to release the external IP when the instance has already created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> gcloud compute addresses list
NAME       REGION        ADDRESS         STATUS
webserver  europe-west1  130.211.70.XXX  IN_USE

gcloud compute addresses delete 130....
```

Or use use 'network' tab in the web interface if it's a one-off need.